# How does Facebook ticker work?

Tags: php, facebook

Most of Facebook is written in PHP but there are a few front end features that use other scripting languages.

Ticker (the small box at the top right of the news feed page displaying recent posts etc etc):

I'm guessing AJAX is involved in this but I was wondering how it all works. I've developed something similar (but more basic) in flash where flash checks every millisecond (as good as real time) for updates but Facebook clearly doesn't use flash for this.

I know data can be passed back and forth with AJAX but how would they make it instant? Constantly checking?

Just wondering

Comment: Wait, you check for updates 3,600,000 times an hour? You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I know :S But I'm not bothered about that. It was just me playing around. Just want know how FB does it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are using long polling

- Request is being sent to the server
- Request does not close the connection until there are news
- Once there are news, script closes the connection and news are visible

Long polling PHP script can look like

```
$seconds = 1;
while($seconds < 60) { // browser can enforce one minute timeout
    $updates = get_updates();    //check for updates
    if ($updates) {
        echo $updates; // json encoded string
        die();
    }
    $seconds++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. So what's the sleep(1) there for?

Comment: @Nav: It ensures that you're polling the database only once a second. It just sleeps for one second, as stated in documentation

Comment: @zzarbi: It was 55 seconds. I can't check if it changed, because there is a lot of activity in my ticker

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably done with polling (i.e. constant checking as you call it), although 1 millisecond is too frequent. I'm guessing something more of the order of seconds.

They probably remember the last object in your news feed currently and every n seconds retrieve items entered after that, and they update the page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a connection pooling in php with gearman..

You can use the following link for reference..

http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/database-connection-pooling-with-php-and-gearman/

Comment: Pool isn't the thing the browser does. Browser polls, not pools