# ClientJade - Trouble executing jade.render()

Tags: node.js, pug

I've run into a problem in the clientside code for a Node.js app I'm working on.
The idea behind this is to update the browser immediately as the socket receives an event.

This is the script block on the client side:

```
script(src='/scripts/jadeTemplate.js')
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(type='text/javascript')
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('obj', function(obj) {
    var newsItem = document.createElement("item");
    jade.render(newsItem, 'objTemplate', { object: obj });
    $('#newsfeed').prepend(newsItem);
    alert(obj);
  });
```

When the `alert()` is placed before the `jade.render()`, it alerts, but if inserted after, it doesn't execute (hence, I think it's a problem with the `jade.render()`).

This is objTemplate.jade, referred to in line 7:

```
p #{object}
// That's it.
```

And this is a relevant snippet from the app.js:

```
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
server.bind(41234);
server.on('message', function(buf, rinfo) {
    isOnline = true;
    var message = buf.toString();
    io.sockets.emit('obj', message);
});
```

---

UPDATE:

[Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/h8CwqFgD) to `/public/scripts/jadeTemplate.js`, which IMO is too long of a snippet for a question.

If I need to provide any more snippets or files let me know. :)

Comment: Can you post jadeTemplate.js?

Comment: Added. I felt it was too long to put in the question itself so I linked to a Pastebin paste, if that's alright. [Also linked here](http://pastebin.com/h8CwqFgD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template doesn't want an attribute `object`, it wants **`obj`**. Try this:

```
socket.on('obj', function(obj) {
    var newsItem = document.createElement("item");
    jade.render(newsItem, 'objTemplate', { obj: obj }); // changed object to obj
    $('#newsfeed').prepend(newsItem);
    alert(obj);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/VeYBY/ shows it working. If you change the attribute back to `object`, you'll get a javascript error in the console.

Comment: Awesome! That was the problem. I'm not sure why I wanted to change the identifier,  because I was afraid that the `obj` key would be interpreted as an identifier as well and the script would try to pass `obj` twice instead of creating a property named "obj" with value `obj`. At any rate, it works now, with that tweak. Thanks again, @Trevor Dixon :)